# Why does a Haskell script using putStrLn hang?

Tags: haskell, printing

On my Windows 7 Home Premium box, why does the following Haskell program hang?

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Hello, World"
```

The script is compiled (using GHC) like this:

```
C:\>ghc --make my_script
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( my_script.hs, my_script.o )
Linking my_script.exe ...
```

The program is then executed like this:

```
C:\>my_script.exe
```

Even after several minutes, there is no output in the **Command Prompt** window.

GHC version is:

```
C:\>ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2
```

(Haskell compiler obtained from https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html.)

---

***Update*** Loading and executing in GHCi yields the following:

```
C:\>ghci my_script.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( my_script.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> main
Hello, World
*Main> :quit
Leaving GHCi.
```

Comment: That's pretty weird. What ghc version, and how did you install it?

Comment: Is that really the exact contents of your file?

Comment: Yes, those are the contents of my file as modeled after the examples of http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output.

Comment: Are you sure that you're in fact editing/showing us `c:\my_script.hs` and not a `my_script.hs` in some other directory?

Comment: Weird. Just for fun, what happens if you run `main` from inside GHCi, instead?

Comment: Try adding an `hFlush stdout` after your `putStrLn`? I'm wondering if something funky is happening with buffers in the Command prompt

Comment: @jkeuhlen Sounds like [dead-chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waving_a_dead_chicken_%28over_it%29) territory to me. `putStrLn` should already flush the buffer.

Comment: Does the Windows command prompt have an equivalent of the *nix-y `which` command? In other words, can you ask whether, when you run `my_script`, it is running the `my_script.exe` that GHC just produced (versus some other thing from elsewhere on your PATH that also happens to be named `my_script`)?

Comment: People are making a good point about shadowing. What if you run it by typing the path? I imagine something like `.\my_script`, but I don't really know Windows too well.

Comment: Unlikely to be the problem here, but some Windows editors replace spaces with tabs, which breaks two-dimensional code. That has caused code that appears correct to break for me.

Comment: Just to make sure, can you delete the exe, the .o and .hi file and recompile?

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you just have the 1-liner `main = putStrLn "Hello, World"`? Might exclude anything to do with spaces vs tabs.